# Registry key - BSXInstaller

Tags: registry

I found in regkey editor folder called BSXInstaller. Path:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> BSXInstaller

Where is this directory comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's linked to the mobile emulator "Bluestacks" if you're not actively using bluestacks, you should delete it as it's just bloatware.